# Scraping google reviews using Rselenium in R

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rselenium

I am exploring how to scrape google reviews using rselenium:

Here is my code

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
library(netstat)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=free_port(), chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$open()
url <- "https://www.google.com/search?q=chans+bend+oreg&sxsrf=APwXEdd-Xmg-_uQOum8A7buBA97FyQqDbQ%3A1681009457208&source=hp&ei=MSsyZM6bCt2H0PEP7oeSoAU&iflsig=AOEireoAAAAAZDI5Qe24Q8NHJ9A_Z90VimpymELKNbhk&ved=0ahUKEwiO-Luc6Jv-AhXdAzQIHe6DBFQQ4dUDCAs&uact=5&oq=chans+bend+oreg&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyDQguEIAEEMcBEK8BEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBwgAEIAEEAoyBggAEBYQHjICCCYyCAgAEIoFEIYDMggIABCKBRCGAzIICAAQigUQhgMyCAgAEIoFEIYDUABYAGDaB2gAcAB4AIABXIgBXJIBATGYAQCgAQKgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz"
remDr$navigate(url)


Sys.sleep(5)

webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = "//span[contains(text(),'Google reviews')]")
webElem$clickElement()

html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

# parse the HTML using rvest
page <- html %>% read_html()

reviews <- page %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@jscontroller="MZnM8e"]') %>%
  html_text()
```

However this code only scrape the reviews that are currently loaded. I need to manually scroll down to the bottom first, if I need to scrape all the reviews.

Will there be a possibility to automate this so that I dont have to manually scroll down?

Thank you

Comment: This can be easily done in python. See https://medium.com/@isguzarsezgin/scraping-google-reviews-with-selenium-python-23135ffcc331